# A lower bound for $\left|\int_a^b f(t) dt\right|$.

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

It is known that, if $f : [a; b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is integrable, then $f$ is bounded, $|f|$ is integrable and
$$\left|\int_a^b f(t) dt\right|\leq \int_a^b|f(t)|dt$$
My question is the following. From these assumptions can be derived the following lower bound? Namely, there exist a constant C such that
$$\left|\int_a^b f(t) dt\right|\geq C \int_a^b|f(t)|dt$$

Comment: Inasmuch as $\int f(x) dx$ can be zero, all that we can deduce is that $C=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow $C\leq 0$ then your assertion is always true take $C=0$ for every function.

Now if you restrict $c>0$ the the answer is simply no! because we can take the function $x\to \sin(x)$ for $x\in [0,2\pi]$ the first integeral is clearly null and the second one is equal to $2$

Comment: Yes.  So, $C=0$ works, does it not?

Comment: If he allows $c=0$, so we can take $c=0$ for al functions and the Op's assertion is always true, and equivalent to the absulate value of a real is positive which is obvious

Comment: He asked if there exists a $C$ for which the inequality is true.  There is!  $C-0$ ... I found one!

Comment: And now is my answer complete or should I delete it!

Comment: @ Elaqqad An up vote for you!